# Call Failed vs No Answer on Skype?

Tags: skype

What's the difference between those 2 on Skype? They both don't work to call but what's the difference between that?

Comment: One means the other party didn't recieve a call or the call itself failed the other means the other party didn't answer the call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No answer means everything went okay as far as Skype is concerned.  It was able to communicate with the remote number, and they didn't answer.

Call Failed means that something went wrong on the backend, and that the communication to the other number failed.  The other number may never have actually received the request, or your system may never have detected a successful connection.

Comment: So how to troubleshoot the Call Failed part?

Comment: When you say no answer means everything went okay and 'they didn't answer', that it effectively rung out? I'm a little confused by this. In my experience from beginning the dial (ie entering a number and then pressing answer) to getting the "No answer" message takes 7 seconds. At no point do I hear any dialling, which happens on other numbers .To claim that 'they didn't answer' is technically correct but somewhat disingenuous, if no time is given to answer.